# Compendium or catalog of compound distributions?

Tags: distributions, references, mixture-distribution, compound-distributions

Does anyone know of a good compendium or catalog of compound distributions, or finite mixture representations of those distributions?

I am trying to find out to what extent the common multi-parameter distributions and their generalized forms can be built up from single parameter distributions through compounding. The ones I have found so far cover only 10 or 15 distributions, and I still can not tell if it is possible to build up e.g. most four parameter distributions from one parameter distributions by successive steps of compounding.

Comment: Look at the list of references here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution